# problem in middle of command-line interface installation

Tags: angular, angular-cli

i am new to all of this angular concept and framework. 
I want to get into it now but as a beginner
I am having problem need some help from you guys.

This is what i get in middle of installation

#### Error I'm getting

[image: Error I'm getting]]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by entering this line:

**npm set strict-ssl false**

and then continuing... npm install -g @angular/cli etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:`npm cache clean --force`
And then re-run the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Hopefully helps.